# Calculate $\int_{\Gamma^{+}} (\operatorname{Im} z)^{2} + ze^\frac{1}{z-1}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis

Calculate 
$$\int_{\Gamma^{+}} (\operatorname{Im} z)^{2} + ze^\frac{1}{z-1}dz;$$ where $\Gamma^{+} $ is positively oriented edge of square $ A(0,-1), B(2,-1), C(2,1), D(0,1)$.

I am little confused with this. Should I be using the Cauchy's theorem for square or Cauchy's integral formula ( for example on opet set $K (1,2)$)?

Comment: break up the sum first, calculate the integral of imaginary part directly. Note the remaining integral is not holomorphic in your contour so you will need to be careful how you evaluate it